# How to fix Ubuntu 18.04 LTS random freezes again

Tags: ubuntu

he a lot of question on topic How to fix Ubuntu 18.04 LTS random freezes

I tested following command

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04
[sudo] Mot de passe de francis : 
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances       
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
linux-generic-hwe-18.04 est déjà la version la plus récente (5.4.0.53.59~18.04.47).
linux-generic-hwe-18.04 passé en « installé manuellement ».
xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04 est déjà la version la plus récente (1:7.7+19ubuntu8~18.04.3).
xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04 passé en « installé manuellement ».
0 mis à jour, 0 nouvellement installés, 0 à enlever et 10 non mis à jour.
```

I have the last version

I use also Logs
there is important part

```
10:17:48 wpa_supplicant: bgscan simple: Failed to enable signal strength monitoring
10:16:50 spice-vdagent: Cannot access vdagent virtio channel /dev/virtio-ports/com.redhat.spice.0
10:16:49 pulseaudio: [pulseaudio] backend-ofono.c: Failed to register as a handsfree audio agent with ofono: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.ofono was not provided by any .service files
10:16:46 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 619444 [ IBUS ]
10:16:39 wpa_supplicant: bgscan simple: Failed to enable signal strength monitoring
10:16:37 spice-vdagent: Cannot access vdagent virtio channel /dev/virtio-ports/com.redhat.spice.0
10:16:35 gnome-session-b: CRITICAL: Unable to create a DBus proxy for GnomeScreensaver: Erreur lors de l’appel de StartServiceByName pour org.gnome.ScreenSaver : GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.gnome.ScreenSaver exited with status 1
10:16:34 wpa_supplicant: dbus: Failed to construct signal
10:16:32 kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO read of 00000000 FAULT at 10ac08 [ IBUS ]
10:16:32 systemd: Failed to start Load Kernel Modules.
10:16:31 kernel: tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: [Firmware Bug]: ACPI region does not cover the entire command/response buffer. [mem 0xfed40000-0xfed4087f flags 0x200] vs fed40080 f80
```

what kind of action to solve my problem because I have a lot of freeze linux

Comment: Are you running Ubuntu in a VM? I'm curious about the `spice-vdagent`.

Comment: I think no. But i use texlive2019. Perhaps it's use VM.